# TextView setText() causes ScrollView to automatically scroll

Tags: android, scrollview, android-constraintlayout

I have in my root `ConstraintLayout` only `Toolbar`, `TextView` and `ScrollView`. When my `Runnable` calls `setText()` on `TextView` and my `ScrollView` was scrolled to the most bottom, the `ScrollView` automatically scrolls up for a height of the `Toolbar`.

It does not deal with stealing focus as `getCurrentFocus()` returns `null` all the way.

Answer (score 0):

So I've created this topic as It took me whole day to find solution.

Updating ConstraintLayout dependency in my app Gradle solved the issue.

It was initially `1.1.3` in my project. Now it is `2.0.4`
`'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'`

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem resolved when I set `TextView` attributes `android:layout_width` and `android:layout_height` to a fixed size (like `"56dp"`) instead of `"wrap_content"`. Not a proper solution, but still useful.